# get the same data order in stack bar python plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, plotly-python

created a stack bar chart to visualize time distribution for each of the day of machine. But cant geth same data order in stack bar.

Ex: Day 01-09, the original data order is Running(36068 sec.) and state B(6842 sec.) but in the stacked bar , the first one is State B and then Running state. Like this can we get the same data order in stack bar?

[image]

code with Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day-Shift': {0: 'Day 01-05',
  1: 'Day 01-05',
  2: 'Day 01-05',
  3: 'Day 01-05',
  4: 'Night 01-05',
  5: 'Day 01-06',
  6: 'Day 01-06',
  7: 'Day 01-06',
  8: 'Day 01-06',
  9: 'Day 01-06',
  10: 'Day 01-06',
  11: 'Night 01-06',
  12: 'Day 01-07',
  13: 'Night 01-07',
  14: 'Night 01-07',
  15: 'Night 01-07',
  16: 'Night 01-07',
  17: 'Night 01-07',
  18: 'Night 01-08',
  19: 'Night 01-08',
  20: 'Night 01-08',
  21: 'Night 01-08',
  22: 'Day 01-08',
  23: 'Day 01-08',
  24: 'Day 01-08',
  25: 'Night 01-09',
  26: 'Night 01-09',
  27: 'Night 01-09',
  28: 'Day 01-09',
  29: 'Day 01-09',
  30: 'Day 01-09',
  31: 'Day 01-09',
  32: 'Day 01-10',
  33: 'Night 01-10',
  34: 'Day 01-11',
  35: 'Day 01-11',
  36: 'Day 01-11',
  37: 'Day 01-11',
  38: 'Day 01-11',
  39: 'Night 01-11',
  40: 'Day 01-12',
  41: 'Night 01-12',
  42: 'Day 01-13',
  43: 'Day 01-13',
  44: 'Day 01-13',
  45: 'Day 01-13',
  46: 'Day 01-13',
  47: 'Day 01-13',
  48: 'Day 01-13',
  49: 'Night 01-13',
  50: 'Day 01-14',
  51: 'Day 01-14',
  52: 'Day 01-14',
  53: 'Day 01-14',
  54: 'Day 01-14',
  55: 'Day 01-14',
  56: 'Day 01-14',
  57: 'Day 01-14',
  58: 'Day 01-14',
  59: 'Night 01-14'},
 'State': {0: 'D',
  1: 'STOPPED',
  2: 'B',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A1',
  7: 'A2',
  8: 'A3',
  9: 'A4',
  10: 'B1',
  11: 'B1',
  12: 'B1',
  13: 'B1',
  14: 'B2',
  15: 'STOPPED',
  16: 'RUNNING',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'STOPPED',
  19: 'B',
  20: 'RUNNING',
  21: 'D',
  22: 'STOPPED',
  23: 'B',
  24: 'RUNNING',
  25: 'STOPPED',
  26: 'RUNNING',
  27: 'B',
  28: 'RUNNING',
  29: 'STOPPED',
  30: 'B',
  31: 'D',
  32: 'B',
  33: 'B',
  34: 'B',
  35: 'RUNNING',
  36: 'STOPPED',
  37: 'D',
  38: 'A',
  39: 'A',
  40: 'A',
  41: 'A',
  42: 'A',
  43: 'A1',
  44: 'A2',
  45: 'A3',
  46: 'A4',
  47: 'B1',
  48: 'B2',
  49: 'B2',
  50: 'B2',
  51: 'B',
  52: 'STOPPED',
  53: 'A',
  54: 'A1',
  55: 'A2',
  56: 'A3',
  57: 'A4',
  58: 'B1',
  59: 'B1'},
 'seconds': {0: 7439,
  1: 0,
  2: 10,
  3: 35751,
  4: 43200,
  5: 7198,
  6: 18,
  7: 14,
  8: 29301,
  9: 6,
  10: 6663,
  11: 43200,
  12: 43200,
  13: 5339,
  14: 8217,
  15: 0,
  16: 4147,
  17: 1040,
  18: 24787,
  19: 1500,
  20: 14966,
  21: 1410,
  22: 2499,
  23: 1310,
  24: 39391,
  25: 3570,
  26: 17234,
  27: 47390,
  28: 36068,
  29: 270,
  30: 6842,
  31: 20,
  32: 43200,
  33: 43200,
  34: 2486,
  35: 8420,
  36: 870,
  37: 30,
  38: 31394,
  39: 43200,
  40: 43200,
  41: 43200,
  42: 36733,
  43: 23,
  44: 6,
  45: 4,
  46: 4,
  47: 3,
  48: 6427,
  49: 43200,
  50: 620,
  51: 0,
  52: 4,
  53: 41336,
  54: 4,
  55: 4,
  56: 4,
  57: 23,
  58: 1205,
  59: 43200}})

dfs = df['Day-Shift'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)([^a-zA-Z]+)', expand=True)
dfs.columns = ['tod', 'date']
dfs['date2'] = dfs['date'] + '-2021'
dfs['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(dfs['date2'])

df = pd.concat([df, dfs], axis = 1)
df = df.sort_values(['date2', 'tod'], ascending = [True, True])

new_order = list(df['Day-Shift'].unique())
# df['Day-Shift'] = pd.Categorical(df['Day-Shift'], categories=new_order, ordered=True)

fig = px.bar(df, x="Day-Shift", y="seconds", color="State",
            category_orders = {'Day-Shift': new_order})
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Plotly cares about the order you add data.

So to reverse each bar, you have to reverse the order plotly receives the data for each bar.

For you, this means that for every day/night, you'll need to reverse the values, like I have below.

Here's the code:

```py
import json

## Get the values of each data dict as lists
shifts  = list(data['Shifts'].values())
seconds = list(data['Seconds'].values())
states  = list(data['States'].values())

shifts_indexed = []
shift_indexed  = []

## Put each shift's indexes into a separate list
## Then those lists into a list of index lists
for index in range(len(shifts)):

    shift = shifts[index]

    ## Can't get previous index yet because there isn't one
    if index == 0:

        shift_indexed.append(index)

    ## If index is the last one
    elif index == (len(shifts)-1):

        shift_indexed.append(index)
        shifts_indexed.append(shift_indexed)

    ## Compare all other shifts to the last shift to see if it's a new shift
    ## If it's a new shift, add the shift's index to the list of shifts
    ## Then reset the shift_indexed list for the next shift
    else:

        last_index = index - 1
        last_shift = shifts[last_index]

        ## Shift is different
        if shift != last_shift:

            ## Add the shifts index list to list of shifts
            shifts_indexed.append(shift_indexed)

            ## Clear the list for the next shift
            shift_indexed = []

            ## Add the new shift to the newly cleared index list
            shift_indexed.append(index)

        ## Shift is the same
        else:

            shift_indexed.append(index)

## Remake dictionary

fixed        = {}

fixed_shifts = {}
fixed_secs   = {}
fixed_states = {}

## For each list of shift indexes
for list in shifts_indexed:

    # Get the list of shift indexes but in reverse
    r_list = list[:None:-1]

    ## Create dictionaries using the indexes in the reversed index list (r_list)
    for i in range(len(list)):

        index   = list[i]
        r_index = r_list[i]

        shift   = shifts[index]
        second  = seconds[index]
        state   = states[index]

        fixed_shifts[r_index] = shift
        fixed_secs[r_index]   = second
        fixed_states[r_index] = state

## Set to final dictionary
fixed['Shifts']  = fixed_shifts
fixed['Seconds'] = fixed_secs
fixed['States']  = fixed_states

print('\nData\n\n'+json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
print('\nFixed\n\n'+json.dumps(fixed, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

**Before:**

```py
data = {

        'Shifts': {
            0: 'Day 01-05',
            1: 'Day 01-05',
            2: 'Day 01-05',
            3: 'Day 01-05'
        },

        'States':     {
            0: 'D',
            1: 'STOPPED',
            2: 'B',
            3: 'A'
        },

        'Seconds':   {
            0: 7439,
            1: 0,
            2: 10,
            3: 35751
        }
    
}
```

**After:**

```py
data = {

        'Shifts': {
            0: 'Day 01-05',
            1: 'Day 01-05',
            2: 'Day 01-05',
            3: 'Day 01-05'
        },

        'States':     {
            0: 'A',
            1: 'B',
            2: 'STOPPED',
            3: 'D'
        },

        'Seconds':   {

            0: 35751,
            1: 10,
            2: 0,
            3: 7439
        }

}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on your answer with code?

Comment: @domahc I've updated my answer with the working code